# Change text color as the user is typing?

Tags: android, android-edittext, string-formatting

While the user is typing in an EditText I would like certain keywords to change colors.
I could place HTML tags around the keywords when the app discovers the user typed it and use Html.fromHtml but the user will be entering real HTML tags themselves and that would mess it up. So I guess I should use Spannable?

And how exactly should I scan the EditText for these keywords? Meaning - what is the most efficient way? I was thinking maybe an array of all the keywords - and then loop through and see if any matches are found . Any ideas on how to approach this?

Answer (score 2):

Hi Use TextWatcher on EditText to see what user is typing and use Linkify to check pattern.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/util/Linkify.html

```
EditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
```

}

Use onTextChanged Listener to check what user is typing.

Sample for Pattern matching..
    int flags = Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE;
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\[0-9]*\", flags);
Linkify.addLinks(myTextView, p,
"content://com.foo");

Comment: Yeah I looked at linkify and it is almost exactly what i need except for the fact I dont want to make clickable links.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Pattern Matcher and match pattern with Text in onTextChanged Listener

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.Spannable;
import android.text.SpannableStringBuilder;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.text.style.ForegroundColorSpan;
import android.text.style.StyleSpan;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class ColorEditText extends Activity {

private Pattern helloPattern = Pattern.compile("Hello");
private Pattern simplePattern = Pattern.compile("Simple");
private SpannableStringBuilder spannable;
private EditText edit;
private TextWatcher colorChangeText;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_color_edit_text);

    edit =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit);

    colorChangeText = new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
            int count) {

            edit.removeTextChangedListener(colorChangeText);    

            Log.d("Changes",edit.getText().toString());

            spannable = new SpannableStringBuilder( edit.getText().toString() );

            Matcher o = helloPattern.matcher(spannable);    


            while (o.find()) {

                spannable.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), o.start(), o.end(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
                spannable.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.rgb(103, 58,  183)), o.start(), o.end(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

            }

            Matcher n = simplePattern.matcher(spannable);

            while (n.find()) {
                 spannable.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), n.start(), n.end(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
                 spannable.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.rgb(0, 105,  92)), n.start(), n.end(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

            }

            edit.setText(spannable);
            edit.setSelection(spannable.length());

            edit.addTextChangedListener(colorChangeText);
        }



        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {


        }
    };

    edit.addTextChangedListener(colorChangeText);

}
```

}